# Setting timezone to UTC (0) in PHP

Tags: php, date, timezone, utc

Why does this work?

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Currie');
```

But this doesn't seem to take any effect at all?

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

This value doesn't change when setting the timezone to UTC:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
```

I'm using php 5.2.13, and the timezone of my server is:

```
$server_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
echo $server_tz; //outputs 'America/Guayaquil'
```

This is the original code:

```
echo time() . "<br>\n";
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo time() . "<br>\n";
```

Output:

```
1317235130
1317235130
```

Comment: How do you know it hasn't taken any effect?

Comment: Because time() prints the same original value and my server is not on UTC tz.

Comment: `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time());` and see what the timezone is.

Comment: @Herbert 2011-09-28 13:23:13 ECT

Comment: @Herbert the date will just convert the time stamp to a defined date, the output will be the same for the values before and after the     date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The problem is that you're displaying `time()`, which is a UNIX timestamp based on GMT/UTC. That’s why it doesn’t change. `date()` on the other hand, *formats* the time based on that timestamp.

A *timestamp* is the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

```php
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time()) . "<br>\n";
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time()) . "<br>\n";
```

Comment: 2011-09-28 13:23:13 ECT ---- 2011-09-28 18:23:13

Comment: UTC is a valid identifier then. Try the new code I posted and let us know what it says.

Comment: this is the new output: America/Guayaquil ---- 2011-09-28 13:32:39 ECT ---- 2011-09-28 18:32:39 UTC ---- 2011-09-29 04:32:39 EST

Comment: It works fine. Notice the differences in hours and the **UTC** in the second item. I don't know what you were doing, but it works just fine. Perhaps you should show your _actual_ code in your question.

Comment: i posted the original code... it works when using the date() function, but it doesn't when using the plain time() function... maybe it was that, right?

Comment: does `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` affect the overall server timezone?

Answer (score 21):

`UTC` is definitely a valid timezone. It is simply an abbreviation for Coordinated Universal Time. In addition, remember that `date_default_timezone_set` accepts one of the following values:

```
    $timezones=array(
    "America/Adak",
    "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
    "America/Argentina/La_Rioja",
    "America/Argentina/San_Luis",
    "America/Atikokan",
    "America/Belem",
    "America/Boise",
    "America/Caracas",
    "America/Chihuahua",
    "America/Cuiaba",
    "America/Denver",
    "America/El_Salvador",
    "America/Godthab",
    "America/Guatemala",
    "America/Hermosillo",
    "America/Indiana/Tell_City",
    "America/Inuvik",
    "America/Kentucky/Louisville",
    "America/Lima",
    "America/Managua",
    "America/Mazatlan",
    "America/Mexico_City",
    "America/Montreal",
    "America/Nome",
    "America/Ojinaga",
    "America/Port-au-Prince",
    "America/Rainy_River",
    "America/Rio_Branco",
    "America/Santo_Domingo",
    "America/St_Barthelemy",
    "America/St_Vincent",
    "America/Tijuana",
    "America/Whitehorse",
    "America/Anchorage",
    "America/Argentina/Catamarca",
    "America/Argentina/Mendoza",
    "America/Argentina/Tucuman",
    "America/Atka",
    "America/Belize",
    "America/Buenos_Aires",
    "America/Catamarca",
    "America/Coral_Harbour",
    "America/Curacao",
    "America/Detroit",
    "America/Ensenada",
    "America/Goose_Bay",
    "America/Guayaquil",
    "America/Indiana/Indianapolis",
    "America/Indiana/Vevay",
    "America/Iqaluit",
    "America/Kentucky/Monticello",
    "America/Los_Angeles",
    "America/Manaus",
    "America/Mendoza",
    "America/Miquelon",
    "America/Montserrat",
    "America/Noronha",
    "America/Panama",
    "America/Port_of_Spain",
    "America/Rankin_Inlet",
    "America/Rosario",
    "America/Sao_Paulo",
    "America/St_Johns",
    "America/Swift_Current",
    "America/Toronto",
    "America/Winnipeg",
    "America/Anguilla",
    "America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia",
    "America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos",
    "America/Argentina/Ushuaia",
    "America/Bahia",
    "America/Blanc-Sablon",
    "America/Cambridge_Bay",
    "America/Cayenne",
    "America/Cordoba",
    "America/Danmarkshavn",
    "America/Dominica",
    "America/Fort_Wayne",
    "America/Grand_Turk",
    "America/Guyana",
    "America/Indiana/Knox",
    "America/Indiana/Vincennes",
    "America/Jamaica",
    "America/Knox_IN",
    "America/Louisville",
    "America/Marigot",
    "America/Menominee",
    "America/Moncton",
    "America/Nassau",
    "America/North_Dakota/Beulah",
    "America/Pangnirtung",
    "America/Porto_Acre",
    "America/Recife",
    "America/Santa_Isabel",
    "America/Scoresbysund",
    "America/St_Kitts",
    "America/Tegucigalpa",
    "America/Tortola",
    "America/Yakutat",
    "America/Antigua",
    "America/Argentina/Cordoba",
    "America/Argentina/Salta",
    "America/Aruba",
    "America/Bahia_Banderas",
    "America/Boa_Vista",
    "America/Campo_Grande",
    "America/Cayman",
    "America/Costa_Rica",
    "America/Dawson",
    "America/Edmonton",
    "America/Fortaleza",
    "America/Grenada",
    "America/Halifax",
    "America/Indiana/Marengo",
    "America/Indiana/Winamac",
    "America/Jujuy",
    "America/Kralendijk",
    "America/Lower_Princes",
    "America/Martinique",
    "America/Merida",
    "America/Monterrey",
    "America/New_York",
    "America/North_Dakota/Center",
    "America/Paramaribo",
    "America/Porto_Velho",
    "America/Regina",
    "America/Santarem",
    "America/Shiprock",
    "America/St_Lucia",
    "America/Thule",
    "America/Vancouver",
    "America/Yellowknife",
    "America/Araguaina",
    "America/Argentina/Jujuy",
    "America/Argentina/San_Juan",
    "America/Asuncion",
    "America/Barbados",
    "America/Bogota",
    "America/Cancun",
    "America/Chicago",
    "America/Creston",
    "America/Dawson_Creek",
    "America/Eirunepe",
    "America/Glace_Bay",
    "America/Guadeloupe",
    "America/Havana",
    "America/Indiana/Petersburg",
    "America/Indianapolis",
    "America/Juneau",
    "America/La_Paz",
    "America/Maceio",
    "America/Matamoros",
    "America/Metlakatla",
    "America/Montevideo",
    "America/Nipigon",
    "America/North_Dakota/New_Salem",
    "America/Phoenix",
    "America/Puerto_Rico",
    "America/Resolute",
    "America/Santiago",
    "America/Sitka",
    "America/St_Thomas",
    "America/Thunder_Bay",
    "America/Virgin",
    "Indian/Antananarivo",
    "Indian/Kerguelen",
    "Indian/Reunion",
    "Australia/ACT",
    "Australia/Currie",
    "Australia/Lindeman",
    "Australia/Perth",
    "Australia/Victoria",
    "Europe/Amsterdam",
    "Europe/Berlin",
    "Europe/Chisinau",
    "Europe/Helsinki",
    "Europe/Kiev",
    "Europe/Madrid",
    "Europe/Moscow",
    "Europe/Prague",
    "Europe/Sarajevo",
    "Europe/Tallinn",
    "Europe/Vatican",
    "Europe/Zagreb",
    "Pacific/Apia",
    "Pacific/Efate",
    "Pacific/Galapagos",
    "Pacific/Johnston",
    "Pacific/Marquesas",
    "Pacific/Noumea",
    "Pacific/Ponape",
    "Pacific/Tahiti",
    "Pacific/Wallis",
    "Indian/Chagos",
    "Indian/Mahe",
    "Australia/Adelaide",
    "Australia/Darwin",
    "Australia/Lord_Howe",
    "Australia/Queensland",
    "Australia/West",
    "Europe/Andorra",
    "Europe/Bratislava",
    "Europe/Copenhagen",
    "Europe/Isle_of_Man",
    "Europe/Lisbon",
    "Europe/Malta",
    "Europe/Nicosia",
    "Europe/Riga",
    "Europe/Simferopol",
    "Europe/Tirane",
    "Europe/Vienna",
    "Europe/Zaporozhye",
    "Pacific/Auckland",
    "Pacific/Enderbury",
    "Pacific/Gambier",
    "Pacific/Kiritimati",
    "Pacific/Midway",
    "Pacific/Pago_Pago",
    "Pacific/Port_Moresby",
    "Pacific/Tarawa",
    "Pacific/Yap",
    "Africa/Abidjan",
    "Africa/Asmera",
    "Africa/Blantyre",
    "Africa/Ceuta",
    "Africa/Douala",
    "Africa/Johannesburg",
    "Africa/Kinshasa",
    "Africa/Lubumbashi",
    "Africa/Mbabane",
    "Africa/Niamey",
    "Africa/Timbuktu",
    "Africa/Accra",
    "Africa/Bamako",
    "Africa/Brazzaville",
    "Africa/Conakry",
    "Africa/El_Aaiun",
    "Africa/Juba",
    "Africa/Lagos",
    "Africa/Lusaka",
    "Africa/Mogadishu",
    "Africa/Nouakchott",
    "Africa/Tripoli",
    "Africa/Addis_Ababa",
    "Africa/Bangui",
    "Africa/Bujumbura",
    "Africa/Dakar",
    "Africa/Freetown",
    "Africa/Kampala",
    "Africa/Libreville",
    "Africa/Malabo",
    "Africa/Monrovia",
    "Africa/Ouagadougou",
    "Africa/Tunis",
    "Africa/Algiers",
    "Africa/Banjul",
    "Africa/Cairo",
    "Africa/Dar_es_Salaam",
    "Africa/Gaborone",
    "Africa/Khartoum",
    "Africa/Lome",
    "Africa/Maputo",
    "Africa/Nairobi",
    "Africa/Porto-Novo",
    "Africa/Windhoek",
    "Africa/Asmara",
    "Africa/Bissau",
    "Africa/Casablanca",
    "Africa/Djibouti",
    "Africa/Harare",
    "Africa/Kigali",
    "Africa/Luanda",
    "Africa/Maseru",
    "Africa/Ndjamena",
    "Africa/Sao_Tome",
    "Atlantic/Azores",
    "Atlantic/Faroe",
    "Atlantic/St_Helena",
    "Atlantic/Bermuda",
    "Atlantic/Jan_Mayen",
    "Atlantic/Stanley",
    "Atlantic/Canary",
    "Atlantic/Madeira",
    "Atlantic/Cape_Verde",
    "Atlantic/Reykjavik",
    "Atlantic/Faeroe",
    "Atlantic/South_Georgia",
    "Asia/Aden",
    "Asia/Aqtobe",
    "Asia/Baku",
    "Asia/Calcutta",
    "Asia/Dacca",
    "Asia/Dushanbe",
    "Asia/Hong_Kong",
    "Asia/Jayapura",
    "Asia/Kashgar",
    "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur",
    "Asia/Magadan",
    "Asia/Novokuznetsk",
    "Asia/Pontianak",
    "Asia/Riyadh",
    "Asia/Shanghai",
    "Asia/Tehran",
    "Asia/Ujung_Pandang",
    "Asia/Vladivostok",
    "Asia/Almaty",
    "Asia/Ashgabat",
    "Asia/Bangkok",
    "Asia/Choibalsan",
    "Asia/Damascus",
    "Asia/Gaza",
    "Asia/Hovd",
    "Asia/Jerusalem",
    "Asia/Kathmandu",
    "Asia/Kuching",
    "Asia/Makassar",
    "Asia/Novosibirsk",
    "Asia/Pyongyang",
    "Asia/Saigon",
    "Asia/Singapore",
    "Asia/Tel_Aviv",
    "Asia/Ulaanbaatar",
    "Asia/Yakutsk",
    "Asia/Amman",
    "Asia/Ashkhabad",
    "Asia/Beirut",
    "Asia/Chongqing",
    "Asia/Dhaka",
    "Asia/Harbin",
    "Asia/Irkutsk",
    "Asia/Kabul",
    "Asia/Katmandu",
    "Asia/Kuwait",
    "Asia/Manila",
    "Asia/Omsk",
    "Asia/Qatar",
    "Asia/Sakhalin",
    "Asia/Taipei",
    "Asia/Thimbu",
    "Asia/Ulan_Bator",
    "Asia/Yekaterinburg",
    "Asia/Anadyr",
    "Asia/Baghdad",
    "Asia/Bishkek",
    "Asia/Chungking",
    "Asia/Dili",
    "Asia/Hebron",
    "Asia/Istanbul",
    "Asia/Kamchatka",
    "Asia/Kolkata",
    "Asia/Macao",
    "Asia/Muscat",
    "Asia/Oral",
    "Asia/Qyzylorda",
    "Asia/Samarkand",
    "Asia/Tashkent",
    "Asia/Thimphu",
    "Asia/Urumqi",
    "Asia/Yerevan",
    "Asia/Aqtau",
    "Asia/Bahrain",
    "Asia/Brunei",
    "Asia/Colombo",
    "Asia/Dubai",
    "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh",
    "Asia/Jakarta",
    "Asia/Karachi",
    "Asia/Krasnoyarsk",
    "Asia/Macau",
    "Asia/Nicosia",
    "Asia/Phnom_Penh",
    "Asia/Rangoon",
    "Asia/Seoul",
    "Asia/Tbilisi",
    "Asia/Tokyo",
    "Asia/Vientiane",
    "Australia/Canberra",
    "Australia/LHI",
    "Australia/NSW",
    "Australia/Tasmania",
    "Australia/Broken_Hill",
    "Australia/Hobart",
    "Australia/North",
    "Australia/Sydney",
    "Pacific/Chuuk",
    "Pacific/Fiji",
    "Pacific/Guam",
    "Pacific/Kwajalein",
    "Pacific/Niue",
    "Pacific/Pitcairn",
    "Pacific/Saipan",
    "Pacific/Truk",
    "Pacific/Chatham",
    "Pacific/Fakaofo",
    "Pacific/Guadalcanal",
    "Pacific/Kosrae",
    "Pacific/Nauru",
    "Pacific/Palau",
    "Pacific/Rarotonga",
    "Pacific/Tongatapu",
    "Pacific/Easter",
    "Pacific/Funafuti",
    "Pacific/Honolulu",
    "Pacific/Majuro",
    "Pacific/Norfolk",
    "Pacific/Pohnpei",
    "Pacific/Samoa",
    "Pacific/Wake",
    "Antarctica/Casey",
    "Antarctica/McMurdo",
    "Antarctica/Vostok",
    "Antarctica/Davis",
    "Antarctica/Palmer",
    "Antarctica/DumontDUrville",
    "Antarctica/Rothera",
    "Antarctica/Macquarie",
    "Antarctica/South_Pole",
    "Antarctica/Mawson",
    "Antarctica/Syowa",
    "Arctic/Longyearbyen",
    "Europe/Athens",
    "Europe/Brussels",
    "Europe/Dublin",
    "Europe/Istanbul",
    "Europe/Ljubljana",
    "Europe/Mariehamn",
    "Europe/Oslo",
    "Europe/Rome",
    "Europe/Skopje",
    "Europe/Tiraspol",
    "Europe/Vilnius",
    "Europe/Zurich",
    "Europe/Belfast",
    "Europe/Bucharest",
    "Europe/Gibraltar",
    "Europe/Jersey",
    "Europe/London",
    "Europe/Minsk",
    "Europe/Paris",
    "Europe/Samara",
    "Europe/Sofia",
    "Europe/Uzhgorod",
    "Europe/Volgograd",
    "Europe/Belgrade",
    "Europe/Budapest",
    "Europe/Guernsey",
    "Europe/Kaliningrad",
    "Europe/Luxembourg",
    "Europe/Monaco",
    "Europe/Podgorica",
    "Europe/San_Marino",
    "Europe/Stockholm",
    "Europe/Vaduz",
    "Europe/Warsaw",
    "Indian/Cocos",
    "Indian/Mauritius",
    "Indian/Christmas",
    "Indian/Maldives",
    "Indian/Comoro",
    "Indian/Mayotte",
    "Australia/Brisbane",
    "Australia/Eucla",
    "Australia/Melbourne",
    "Australia/South",
    "Australia/Yancowinna",
    );
```

Timezones in PHP at http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Where can i find this list of timezones but by country?

Comment: pacific/auckland

Answer (score 18):

> List of entire available timezones.

```
$time_zones = array (
  0 => 'Africa/Abidjan',
  1 => 'Africa/Accra',
  2 => 'Africa/Addis_Ababa',
  3 => 'Africa/Algiers',
  4 => 'Africa/Asmara',
  5 => 'Africa/Asmera',
  6 => 'Africa/Bamako',
  7 => 'Africa/Bangui',
  8 => 'Africa/Banjul',
  9 => 'Africa/Bissau',
  10 => 'Africa/Blantyre',
  11 => 'Africa/Brazzaville',
  12 => 'Africa/Bujumbura',
  13 => 'Africa/Cairo',
  14 => 'Africa/Casablanca',
  15 => 'Africa/Ceuta',
  16 => 'Africa/Conakry',
  17 => 'Africa/Dakar',
  18 => 'Africa/Dar_es_Salaam',
  19 => 'Africa/Djibouti',
  20 => 'Africa/Douala',
  21 => 'Africa/El_Aaiun',
  22 => 'Africa/Freetown',
  23 => 'Africa/Gaborone',
  24 => 'Africa/Harare',
  25 => 'Africa/Johannesburg',
  26 => 'Africa/Juba',
  27 => 'Africa/Kampala',
  28 => 'Africa/Khartoum',
  29 => 'Africa/Kigali',
  30 => 'Africa/Kinshasa',
  31 => 'Africa/Lagos',
  32 => 'Africa/Libreville',
  33 => 'Africa/Lome',
  34 => 'Africa/Luanda',
  35 => 'Africa/Lubumbashi',
  36 => 'Africa/Lusaka',
  37 => 'Africa/Malabo',
  38 => 'Africa/Maputo',
  39 => 'Africa/Maseru',
  40 => 'Africa/Mbabane',
  41 => 'Africa/Mogadishu',
  42 => 'Africa/Monrovia',
  43 => 'Africa/Nairobi',
  44 => 'Africa/Ndjamena',
  45 => 'Africa/Niamey',
  46 => 'Africa/Nouakchott',
  47 => 'Africa/Ouagadougou',
  48 => 'Africa/Porto-Novo',
  49 => 'Africa/Sao_Tome',
  50 => 'Africa/Timbuktu',
  51 => 'Africa/Tripoli',
  52 => 'Africa/Tunis',
  53 => 'Africa/Windhoek',
  54 => 'America/Adak',
  55 => 'America/Anchorage',
  56 => 'America/Anguilla',
  57 => 'America/Antigua',
  58 => 'America/Araguaina',
  59 => 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires',
  60 => 'America/Argentina/Catamarca',
  61 => 'America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia',
  62 => 'America/Argentina/Cordoba',
  63 => 'America/Argentina/Jujuy',
  64 => 'America/Argentina/La_Rioja',
  65 => 'America/Argentina/Mendoza',
  66 => 'America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos',
  67 => 'America/Argentina/Salta',
  68 => 'America/Argentina/San_Juan',
  69 => 'America/Argentina/San_Luis',
  70 => 'America/Argentina/Tucuman',
  71 => 'America/Argentina/Ushuaia',
  72 => 'America/Aruba',
  73 => 'America/Asuncion',
  74 => 'America/Atikokan',
  75 => 'America/Atka',
  76 => 'America/Bahia',
  77 => 'America/Bahia_Banderas',
  78 => 'America/Barbados',
  79 => 'America/Belem',
  80 => 'America/Belize',
  81 => 'America/Blanc-Sablon',
  82 => 'America/Boa_Vista',
  83 => 'America/Bogota',
  84 => 'America/Boise',
  85 => 'America/Buenos_Aires',
  86 => 'America/Cambridge_Bay',
  87 => 'America/Campo_Grande',
  88 => 'America/Cancun',
  89 => 'America/Caracas',
  90 => 'America/Catamarca',
  91 => 'America/Cayenne',
  92 => 'America/Cayman',
  93 => 'America/Chicago',
  94 => 'America/Chihuahua',
  95 => 'America/Coral_Harbour',
  96 => 'America/Cordoba',
  97 => 'America/Costa_Rica',
  98 => 'America/Creston',
  99 => 'America/Cuiaba',
  100 => 'America/Curacao',
  101 => 'America/Danmarkshavn',
  102 => 'America/Dawson',
  103 => 'America/Dawson_Creek',
  104 => 'America/Denver',
  105 => 'America/Detroit',
  106 => 'America/Dominica',
  107 => 'America/Edmonton',
  108 => 'America/Eirunepe',
  109 => 'America/El_Salvador',
  110 => 'America/Ensenada',
  111 => 'America/Fort_Nelson',
  112 => 'America/Fort_Wayne',
  113 => 'America/Fortaleza',
  114 => 'America/Glace_Bay',
  115 => 'America/Godthab',
  116 => 'America/Goose_Bay',
  117 => 'America/Grand_Turk',
  118 => 'America/Grenada',
  119 => 'America/Guadeloupe',
  120 => 'America/Guatemala',
  121 => 'America/Guayaquil',
  122 => 'America/Guyana',
  123 => 'America/Halifax',
  124 => 'America/Havana',
  125 => 'America/Hermosillo',
  126 => 'America/Indiana/Indianapolis',
  127 => 'America/Indiana/Knox',
  128 => 'America/Indiana/Marengo',
  129 => 'America/Indiana/Petersburg',
  130 => 'America/Indiana/Tell_City',
  131 => 'America/Indiana/Vevay',
  132 => 'America/Indiana/Vincennes',
  133 => 'America/Indiana/Winamac',
  134 => 'America/Indianapolis',
  135 => 'America/Inuvik',
  136 => 'America/Iqaluit',
  137 => 'America/Jamaica',
  138 => 'America/Jujuy',
  139 => 'America/Juneau',
  140 => 'America/Kentucky/Louisville',
  141 => 'America/Kentucky/Monticello',
  142 => 'America/Knox_IN',
  143 => 'America/Kralendijk',
  144 => 'America/La_Paz',
  145 => 'America/Lima',
  146 => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  147 => 'America/Louisville',
  148 => 'America/Lower_Princes',
  149 => 'America/Maceio',
  150 => 'America/Managua',
  151 => 'America/Manaus',
  152 => 'America/Marigot',
  153 => 'America/Martinique',
  154 => 'America/Matamoros',
  155 => 'America/Mazatlan',
  156 => 'America/Mendoza',
  157 => 'America/Menominee',
  158 => 'America/Merida',
  159 => 'America/Metlakatla',
  160 => 'America/Mexico_City',
  161 => 'America/Miquelon',
  162 => 'America/Moncton',
  163 => 'America/Monterrey',
  164 => 'America/Montevideo',
  165 => 'America/Montreal',
  166 => 'America/Montserrat',
  167 => 'America/Nassau',
  168 => 'America/New_York',
  169 => 'America/Nipigon',
  170 => 'America/Nome',
  171 => 'America/Noronha',
  172 => 'America/North_Dakota/Beulah',
  173 => 'America/North_Dakota/Center',
  174 => 'America/North_Dakota/New_Salem',
  175 => 'America/Ojinaga',
  176 => 'America/Panama',
  177 => 'America/Pangnirtung',
  178 => 'America/Paramaribo',
  179 => 'America/Phoenix',
  180 => 'America/Port-au-Prince',
  181 => 'America/Port_of_Spain',
  182 => 'America/Porto_Acre',
  183 => 'America/Porto_Velho',
  184 => 'America/Puerto_Rico',
  185 => 'America/Rainy_River',
  186 => 'America/Rankin_Inlet',
  187 => 'America/Recife',
  188 => 'America/Regina',
  189 => 'America/Resolute',
  190 => 'America/Rio_Branco',
  191 => 'America/Rosario',
  192 => 'America/Santa_Isabel',
  193 => 'America/Santarem',
  194 => 'America/Santiago',
  195 => 'America/Santo_Domingo',
  196 => 'America/Sao_Paulo',
  197 => 'America/Scoresbysund',
  198 => 'America/Shiprock',
  199 => 'America/Sitka',
  200 => 'America/St_Barthelemy',
  201 => 'America/St_Johns',
  202 => 'America/St_Kitts',
  203 => 'America/St_Lucia',
  204 => 'America/St_Thomas',
  205 => 'America/St_Vincent',
  206 => 'America/Swift_Current',
  207 => 'America/Tegucigalpa',
  208 => 'America/Thule',
  209 => 'America/Thunder_Bay',
  210 => 'America/Tijuana',
  211 => 'America/Toronto',
  212 => 'America/Tortola',
  213 => 'America/Vancouver',
  214 => 'America/Virgin',
  215 => 'America/Whitehorse',
  216 => 'America/Winnipeg',
  217 => 'America/Yakutat',
  218 => 'America/Yellowknife',
  219 => 'Antarctica/Casey',
  220 => 'Antarctica/Davis',
  221 => 'Antarctica/DumontDUrville',
  222 => 'Antarctica/Macquarie',
  223 => 'Antarctica/Mawson',
  224 => 'Antarctica/McMurdo',
  225 => 'Antarctica/Palmer',
  226 => 'Antarctica/Rothera',
  227 => 'Antarctica/South_Pole',
  228 => 'Antarctica/Syowa',
  229 => 'Antarctica/Troll',
  230 => 'Antarctica/Vostok',
  231 => 'Arctic/Longyearbyen',
  232 => 'Asia/Aden',
  233 => 'Asia/Almaty',
  234 => 'Asia/Amman',
  235 => 'Asia/Anadyr',
  236 => 'Asia/Aqtau',
  237 => 'Asia/Aqtobe',
  238 => 'Asia/Ashgabat',
  239 => 'Asia/Ashkhabad',
  240 => 'Asia/Baghdad',
  241 => 'Asia/Bahrain',
  242 => 'Asia/Baku',
  243 => 'Asia/Bangkok',
  244 => 'Asia/Beirut',
  245 => 'Asia/Bishkek',
  246 => 'Asia/Brunei',
  247 => 'Asia/Calcutta',
  248 => 'Asia/Chita',
  249 => 'Asia/Choibalsan',
  250 => 'Asia/Chongqing',
  251 => 'Asia/Chungking',
  252 => 'Asia/Colombo',
  253 => 'Asia/Dacca',
  254 => 'Asia/Damascus',
  255 => 'Asia/Dhaka',
  256 => 'Asia/Dili',
  257 => 'Asia/Dubai',
  258 => 'Asia/Dushanbe',
  259 => 'Asia/Gaza',
  260 => 'Asia/Harbin',
  261 => 'Asia/Hebron',
  262 => 'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh',
  263 => 'Asia/Hong_Kong',
  264 => 'Asia/Hovd',
  265 => 'Asia/Irkutsk',
  266 => 'Asia/Istanbul',
  267 => 'Asia/Jakarta',
  268 => 'Asia/Jayapura',
  269 => 'Asia/Jerusalem',
  270 => 'Asia/Kabul',
  271 => 'Asia/Kamchatka',
  272 => 'Asia/Karachi',
  273 => 'Asia/Kashgar',
  274 => 'Asia/Kathmandu',
  275 => 'Asia/Katmandu',
  276 => 'Asia/Khandyga',
  277 => 'Asia/Kolkata',
  278 => 'Asia/Krasnoyarsk',
  279 => 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur',
  280 => 'Asia/Kuching',
  281 => 'Asia/Kuwait',
  282 => 'Asia/Macao',
  283 => 'Asia/Macau',
  284 => 'Asia/Magadan',
  285 => 'Asia/Makassar',
  286 => 'Asia/Manila',
  287 => 'Asia/Muscat',
  288 => 'Asia/Nicosia',
  289 => 'Asia/Novokuznetsk',
  290 => 'Asia/Novosibirsk',
  291 => 'Asia/Omsk',
  292 => 'Asia/Oral',
  293 => 'Asia/Phnom_Penh',
  294 => 'Asia/Pontianak',
  295 => 'Asia/Pyongyang',
  296 => 'Asia/Qatar',
  297 => 'Asia/Qyzylorda',
  298 => 'Asia/Rangoon',
  299 => 'Asia/Riyadh',
  300 => 'Asia/Saigon',
  301 => 'Asia/Sakhalin',
  302 => 'Asia/Samarkand',
  303 => 'Asia/Seoul',
  304 => 'Asia/Shanghai',
  305 => 'Asia/Singapore',
  306 => 'Asia/Srednekolymsk',
  307 => 'Asia/Taipei',
  308 => 'Asia/Tashkent',
  309 => 'Asia/Tbilisi',
  310 => 'Asia/Tehran',
  311 => 'Asia/Tel_Aviv',
  312 => 'Asia/Thimbu',
  313 => 'Asia/Thimphu',
  314 => 'Asia/Tokyo',
  315 => 'Asia/Ujung_Pandang',
  316 => 'Asia/Ulaanbaatar',
  317 => 'Asia/Ulan_Bator',
  318 => 'Asia/Urumqi',
  319 => 'Asia/Ust-Nera',
  320 => 'Asia/Vientiane',
  321 => 'Asia/Vladivostok',
  322 => 'Asia/Yakutsk',
  323 => 'Asia/Yekaterinburg',
  324 => 'Asia/Yerevan',
  325 => 'Atlantic/Azores',
  326 => 'Atlantic/Bermuda',
  327 => 'Atlantic/Canary',
  328 => 'Atlantic/Cape_Verde',
  329 => 'Atlantic/Faeroe',
  330 => 'Atlantic/Faroe',
  331 => 'Atlantic/Jan_Mayen',
  332 => 'Atlantic/Madeira',
  333 => 'Atlantic/Reykjavik',
  334 => 'Atlantic/South_Georgia',
  335 => 'Atlantic/St_Helena',
  336 => 'Atlantic/Stanley',
  337 => 'Australia/ACT',
  338 => 'Australia/Adelaide',
  339 => 'Australia/Brisbane',
  340 => 'Australia/Broken_Hill',
  341 => 'Australia/Canberra',
  342 => 'Australia/Currie',
  343 => 'Australia/Darwin',
  344 => 'Australia/Eucla',
  345 => 'Australia/Hobart',
  346 => 'Australia/LHI',
  347 => 'Australia/Lindeman',
  348 => 'Australia/Lord_Howe',
  349 => 'Australia/Melbourne',
  350 => 'Australia/North',
  351 => 'Australia/NSW',
  352 => 'Australia/Perth',
  353 => 'Australia/Queensland',
  354 => 'Australia/South',
  355 => 'Australia/Sydney',
  356 => 'Australia/Tasmania',
  357 => 'Australia/Victoria',
  358 => 'Australia/West',
  359 => 'Australia/Yancowinna',
  360 => 'Europe/Amsterdam',
  361 => 'Europe/Andorra',
  362 => 'Europe/Athens',
  363 => 'Europe/Belfast',
  364 => 'Europe/Belgrade',
  365 => 'Europe/Berlin',
  366 => 'Europe/Bratislava',
  367 => 'Europe/Brussels',
  368 => 'Europe/Bucharest',
  369 => 'Europe/Budapest',
  370 => 'Europe/Busingen',
  371 => 'Europe/Chisinau',
  372 => 'Europe/Copenhagen',
  373 => 'Europe/Dublin',
  374 => 'Europe/Gibraltar',
  375 => 'Europe/Guernsey',
  376 => 'Europe/Helsinki',
  377 => 'Europe/Isle_of_Man',
  378 => 'Europe/Istanbul',
  379 => 'Europe/Jersey',
  380 => 'Europe/Kaliningrad',
  381 => 'Europe/Kiev',
  382 => 'Europe/Lisbon',
  383 => 'Europe/Ljubljana',
  384 => 'Europe/London',
  385 => 'Europe/Luxembourg',
  386 => 'Europe/Madrid',
  387 => 'Europe/Malta',
  388 => 'Europe/Mariehamn',
  389 => 'Europe/Minsk',
  390 => 'Europe/Monaco',
  391 => 'Europe/Moscow',
  392 => 'Europe/Nicosia',
  393 => 'Europe/Oslo',
  394 => 'Europe/Paris',
  395 => 'Europe/Podgorica',
  396 => 'Europe/Prague',
  397 => 'Europe/Riga',
  398 => 'Europe/Rome',
  399 => 'Europe/Samara',
  400 => 'Europe/San_Marino',
  401 => 'Europe/Sarajevo',
  402 => 'Europe/Simferopol',
  403 => 'Europe/Skopje',
  404 => 'Europe/Sofia',
  405 => 'Europe/Stockholm',
  406 => 'Europe/Tallinn',
  407 => 'Europe/Tirane',
  408 => 'Europe/Tiraspol',
  409 => 'Europe/Uzhgorod',
  410 => 'Europe/Vaduz',
  411 => 'Europe/Vatican',
  412 => 'Europe/Vienna',
  413 => 'Europe/Vilnius',
  414 => 'Europe/Volgograd',
  415 => 'Europe/Warsaw',
  416 => 'Europe/Zagreb',
  417 => 'Europe/Zaporozhye',
  418 => 'Europe/Zurich',
  419 => 'Indian/Antananarivo',
  420 => 'Indian/Chagos',
  421 => 'Indian/Christmas',
  422 => 'Indian/Cocos',
  423 => 'Indian/Comoro',
  424 => 'Indian/Kerguelen',
  425 => 'Indian/Mahe',
  426 => 'Indian/Maldives',
  427 => 'Indian/Mauritius',
  428 => 'Indian/Mayotte',
  429 => 'Indian/Reunion',
  430 => 'Pacific/Apia',
  431 => 'Pacific/Auckland',
  432 => 'Pacific/Bougainville',
  433 => 'Pacific/Chatham',
  434 => 'Pacific/Chuuk',
  435 => 'Pacific/Easter',
  436 => 'Pacific/Efate',
  437 => 'Pacific/Enderbury',
  438 => 'Pacific/Fakaofo',
  439 => 'Pacific/Fiji',
  440 => 'Pacific/Funafuti',
  441 => 'Pacific/Galapagos',
  442 => 'Pacific/Gambier',
  443 => 'Pacific/Guadalcanal',
  444 => 'Pacific/Guam',
  445 => 'Pacific/Honolulu',
  446 => 'Pacific/Johnston',
  447 => 'Pacific/Kiritimati',
  448 => 'Pacific/Kosrae',
  449 => 'Pacific/Kwajalein',
  450 => 'Pacific/Majuro',
  451 => 'Pacific/Marquesas',
  452 => 'Pacific/Midway',
  453 => 'Pacific/Nauru',
  454 => 'Pacific/Niue',
  455 => 'Pacific/Norfolk',
  456 => 'Pacific/Noumea',
  457 => 'Pacific/Pago_Pago',
  458 => 'Pacific/Palau',
  459 => 'Pacific/Pitcairn',
  460 => 'Pacific/Pohnpei',
  461 => 'Pacific/Ponape',
  462 => 'Pacific/Port_Moresby',
  463 => 'Pacific/Rarotonga',
  464 => 'Pacific/Saipan',
  465 => 'Pacific/Samoa',
  466 => 'Pacific/Tahiti',
  467 => 'Pacific/Tarawa',
  468 => 'Pacific/Tongatapu',
  469 => 'Pacific/Truk',
  470 => 'Pacific/Wake',
  471 => 'Pacific/Wallis',
  472 => 'Pacific/Yap',
  473 => 'Brazil/Acre',
  474 => 'Brazil/DeNoronha',
  475 => 'Brazil/East',
  476 => 'Brazil/West',
  477 => 'Canada/Atlantic',
  478 => 'Canada/Central',
  479 => 'Canada/East-Saskatchewan',
  480 => 'Canada/Eastern',
  481 => 'Canada/Mountain',
  482 => 'Canada/Newfoundland',
  483 => 'Canada/Pacific',
  484 => 'Canada/Saskatchewan',
  485 => 'Canada/Yukon',
  486 => 'CET',
  487 => 'Chile/Continental',
  488 => 'Chile/EasterIsland',
  489 => 'CST6CDT',
  490 => 'Cuba',
  491 => 'EET',
  492 => 'Egypt',
  493 => 'Eire',
  494 => 'EST',
  495 => 'EST5EDT',
  496 => 'Etc/GMT',
  497 => 'Etc/GMT+0',
  498 => 'Etc/GMT+1',
  499 => 'Etc/GMT+10',
  500 => 'Etc/GMT+11',
  501 => 'Etc/GMT+12',
  502 => 'Etc/GMT+2',
  503 => 'Etc/GMT+3',
  504 => 'Etc/GMT+4',
  505 => 'Etc/GMT+5',
  506 => 'Etc/GMT+6',
  507 => 'Etc/GMT+7',
  508 => 'Etc/GMT+8',
  509 => 'Etc/GMT+9',
  510 => 'Etc/GMT-0',
  511 => 'Etc/GMT-1',
  512 => 'Etc/GMT-10',
  513 => 'Etc/GMT-11',
  514 => 'Etc/GMT-12',
  515 => 'Etc/GMT-13',
  516 => 'Etc/GMT-14',
  517 => 'Etc/GMT-2',
  518 => 'Etc/GMT-3',
  519 => 'Etc/GMT-4',
  520 => 'Etc/GMT-5',
  521 => 'Etc/GMT-6',
  522 => 'Etc/GMT-7',
  523 => 'Etc/GMT-8',
  524 => 'Etc/GMT-9',
  525 => 'Etc/GMT0',
  526 => 'Etc/Greenwich',
  527 => 'Etc/UCT',
  528 => 'Etc/Universal',
  529 => 'Etc/UTC',
  530 => 'Etc/Zulu',
  531 => 'Factory',
  532 => 'GB',
  533 => 'GB-Eire',
  534 => 'GMT',
  535 => 'GMT+0',
  536 => 'GMT-0',
  537 => 'GMT0',
  538 => 'Greenwich',
  539 => 'Hongkong',
  540 => 'HST',
  541 => 'Iceland',
  542 => 'Iran',
  543 => 'Israel',
  544 => 'Jamaica',
  545 => 'Japan',
  546 => 'Kwajalein',
  547 => 'Libya',
  548 => 'MET',
  549 => 'Mexico/BajaNorte',
  550 => 'Mexico/BajaSur',
  551 => 'Mexico/General',
  552 => 'MST',
  553 => 'MST7MDT',
  554 => 'Navajo',
  555 => 'NZ',
  556 => 'NZ-CHAT',
  557 => 'Poland',
  558 => 'Portugal',
  559 => 'PRC',
  560 => 'PST8PDT',
  561 => 'ROC',
  562 => 'ROK',
  563 => 'Singapore',
  564 => 'Turkey',
  565 => 'UCT',
  566 => 'Universal',
  567 => 'US/Alaska',
  568 => 'US/Aleutian',
  569 => 'US/Arizona',
  570 => 'US/Central',
  571 => 'US/East-Indiana',
  572 => 'US/Eastern',
  573 => 'US/Hawaii',
  574 => 'US/Indiana-Starke',
  575 => 'US/Michigan',
  576 => 'US/Mountain',
  577 => 'US/Pacific',
  578 => 'US/Pacific-New',
  579 => 'US/Samoa',
  580 => 'UTC',
  581 => 'W-SU',
  582 => 'WET',
  583 => 'Zulu',
)
```

Comment: Element 565: "UCT"??

Comment: South Africa Standard Time.
Time zone in **University of Cape Town**, Rondebosch, Cape Town, South Africa (GMT+2)

Answer (score 12):

Is 'UTC' a valid timezone identifier on your system?

```
<?php
if (date_default_timezone_set('UTC')){
    echo "UTC is a valid time zone";
}else{
    echo "The system doesn't know WTFUTC.  Maybe try updating tzinfo with your package manager?";
}
```

Comment: I see your point. Actually im on a development environment (Mac OSX). It seems the utc is not a valid timezone for some reason. How could i emulate that value?

Comment: Do `print_r( DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() );` to list the available timezones and see if UTC has a different name on the system.

Comment: That's strange.  Does /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC exist?

Answer (score 2):

In PHP DateTime (PHP >= 5.3)

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $dt->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always check this maintained list to timezones

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php