# Change date() to central time

Tags: php, date, timezone

I have figured out how to get the time using `date('g:i a', time())` to output on the chat i'm making. It outputs something like 7:54 pm. The promlem is that I am in the Central Timezone and it is 8:54 my time. I tried using `date('g' + 1 + ':i a', time())` but that didn't work. Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Could [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript) be of use? Are you using any time-handling libraries, like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting timezone to UTC (0) in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587435/setting-timezone-to-utc-0-in-php)

Comment: no, I'm just using pure js. I thought it was easier to convert to different timezones.

Comment: Your code is PHP, not JavaScript

Comment: no duh. I was talking about the first comment. Thankyou for solving my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with [`DateTimeZone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php):

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
echo $date->format('g:i a');
```

I use [`date_default_timezone_get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) to get the current time zone and then change it using [`DateTime::setTimeZone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)