# Not able to get current Timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

Need help getting pulling timestamp from database. timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
I need it to show our current timezone EST time. Need help doing this.

current query

```
    mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_leadsscott = "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE marketer = 'scott' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC";
$leadsscott = mysql_query($query_leadsscott, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_leadsscott = mysql_fetch_assoc($leadsscott);
$totalRows_leadsscott = mysql_num_rows($leadsscott);` 



' <h6>Marketing Reports for Emily</h6>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Timestamp</td>
        <td>Marketer</td>
        <td>Facility</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Cocality</td>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>Zip</td>
        <td>Latlng</td>
      </tr>
      <?php do { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row_leadsemily['timestamp']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_leadsemily['marketer']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_leadsemily['facility']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_leadsemily['name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_leadsemily['type']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_leadsemily['description']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_leadsemily['locality']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_leadsemily['state']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row_leadsemily['zip']; ?></td>
          <td><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/<?php echo $row_leadsemily['latlng']; ?>"> Link </a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_leadsemily = mysql_fetch_assoc($leadsemily)); ?>
    </table>'
```

Timestamp that shows back on report time as follows

Timestamp
2016-05-09 13:16:57

I need this to show EST it is currently showing UTC time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the offset is always the same you can just modify your output and leave the timestamp in the db as UTC:

```
 DATE_ADD(timestamp, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

Comment: How did I do this? In my table data?

Comment: Just use this for your query: `SELECT DATE_ADD(timestamp, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) FROM leads WHERE marketer = 'scott' ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC`

Comment: You have to add all fileds you might want to get so it might look like this:    `SELECT
     DATE_ADD(timestamp, INTERVAL 2 HOUR),
     marketer,
     facility,
     name,
     type,
     description,
     locality, 
     state,
     zip,
    FROM 
     leads 
    WHERE 
     marketer = 'scott' ORDER BY`

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE  DATE_ADD(timestamp, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AND marketer <>  'Tommy' AND DATE(`timestamp`) = CURDATE() ORDER BY 'timestamp' ASC";`

Is not changing time interval

Comment: you must use it instead of the `*` after the `SELECT`

Comment: Using the following in MYSQL
`SELECT DATE_ADD(timestamp, INTERVAL 2 HOUR), marketer, facility, name, type, description, locality, state, zip, FROM leads WHERE marketer = 'scott';`
I get the error! 
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM leads LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1`

Comment: Is there a way i can send my script to be looked at? This just has me puzzled and have looked everywhere, google, MySQL forums  and documents. called my hosting and am not able to have the time zone changed unless hosting a dedicated server.

Comment: You can update the code in your question above. The error you got is not from the posted query. Do you have more querys in your code? Make sure that each query ends with `;` otherwhise mysql will mix up two or more querys to one which will lead to an error.

Answer (score 0):

remove this

```
 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

then check the query. If this works fine means then sort the timestamp as follows

```
 order by year  DESC, month DESC, day DESC"
```

Comment: Timestamp that shows back on report time as follows

Timestamp 
2016-05-09 13:16:57 

I need this to show EST it is currently showing UTC time which is three hours behind

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('EST'); echo $row_leadsemily['timestamp'];   refer the timezone set here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33163392/3548072

Comment: <td><?php date_default_timezone_set('EST'); echo $row_leadsemily['timestamp']; ?></td> this didnt change the timezone still receiving UTC time from database  @ARUN.G

Comment: You need to check the datetime field in mysql after inserting a row (echo now();) if this is your timezone? then all fine else convert to ur timezone then manually insert the time stamp refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10184834/3548072 and post your data insertion code