# hh:mm:ss difference return wrong answer in php

Tags: php, datetime

I am using this code to calculate the time period. In fact, I want the period between two HH:MM:SS moment and have a result in HH:MM:SS format.

```
$time1 = strtotime('00:00:00');
$time2 = strtotime('00:00:07');
$diff = $time2 - $time1;
$diff = date('H:i:s', $diff);
```

I'm expecting `00:00:07` but I get `01:00:07`. What could be the problem?

Irvin run [here](https://eval.in/684340), and get right answer but I run the same code on my local machine and wrong!!
Is it timezone or maybe some configuration effect the result?!

Comment: Everything is working fine with my demo. Exactly same code from you. The result is `00:00:07`. https://eval.in/684340

Comment: @Irvin, I run here on local machine and it give me 01:00:07, It crazy! but maybe it depend on timezone !!??

Comment: Yeah it might be.

Comment: Yes, it's probably a timezone issue. `$diff` is a timestamp in UTC, but `date()` produces the output in the current timezone. You're presumably 1 hour behind UTC.

Comment: simple fix: `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date(); with timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288789/php-date-with-timezone)

Comment: @Fred-ii- , if I set the time zone as UTC , is it temporary! I mean for other functions that use time , it still would be UTC?

Comment: what other functions? and here, this Q&A will most likely explain it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587435/setting-timezone-to-utc-0-in-php mostly the most upvoted/accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7587637/1415724 - it's server dependant and on its location. If you want a user's time/date and if from another location/country etc, then you need to use a JS solution.

Comment: Even though it might work in many cases, this is still a gross misuse of date functions.

Comment: @Sammitch , As you see this is a question not answer ! If you know a way I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please stop using `strtotime` and `date` functions. Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

And if you would have searched better, finding difference for two dates has already been all over SO. For instance, my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718155/subtract-some-date-and-time-from-current-date-and-time-to-find-age-in-php/38718499#38718499). Slightly changed it would look like:

```
$create_time = "00:00:00";
$current_time="00:00:07";

$dtCurrent = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $current_time);
$dtCreate = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $create_time);
$diff = $dtCurrent->diff($dtCreate);

echo $diff->format("%H:%I:%S"); // to get HH:MM:SS format
```

This returns `00:00:07`
See [`DateInterval::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) for more formatting details.

Comment: @Nordenheim, I would accept the answer that solve it , Your answer is good but sometime the times are not right format and it stop my code, I don't want it to happen, In my previous method, even if they are not right format like HH:MM:SS it won't give me internal error. Do you know how to ignore object errors in the case it failed to create object !

Comment: @FarzadSalimiJazi there are a lot of possible answers starting with `error_reporting` setting and ending with poorly designed and implemented architecture that you might have. It all depends on the code you have and might require major refactoring. To get advice on the latter there is [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Everyone: I have just cleaned up a lot of clutter in the comments. The comments are not for extended discussion. Please do not use them to start or finish wars about whether OOP is amazing, a failed experiment, or whatever. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you minus time 1 from time 2 you end up with 7;

The date function needs a timestamp, 7 is not a timestamp.

You could use http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php to calculate the difference instead?

Comment: But I think, It should give me 00:00:07 with 7!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the UNIX epoch which cancels timezone diffrences in ini settings, essentially. it's Jan 1st '70. You can check your server/app's setup for timezone by adding [`e`, `O` or `P`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters). Check [this code](https://3v4l.org/uK2NU):

```
$time1 = strtotime('00:00:00 +0000');
$time2 = strtotime('00:00:07 +0000');
$epoch = strtotime('01 Jan 1970');
$diff = $time2 - $time1;
var_dump($time1,$time2,$epoch,$diff);
$diff = date('H:i:s', $epoch+$diff);
echo $diff;
```